# Memory shortage problem while using BufferedImage and ImageIO to save images

Tags: java, out-of-memory, jai

I want to save some java.awt.Image objects into the disk. But when I try like:

```
for (Image image : images) {
    image = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();
    BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = temp.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    File tempFile = null;
    try {
        tempFile = File.createTempFile("img", ".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(temp, "jpg", tempFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    files.add(tempFile);
}
```

I get java heap space error.

I needed to put

```
image = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();
```

to get all the pixels loaded so that image.getwidth(null) and image.getHeight(null) return valid results.

Is there any other way to do this except for increasing heap size?

Comment: How large are the images? Do you use Xmx to increase the memory? Why don't you use ImageIO.read(URL) and friends to get the image as BufferedImage?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need to ImageIcon, and why you need to paint the image with a Graphics context. What happens if you iterate `images` with only the `try/catch` block?

Comment: @kd304
Images can be in any size. I'm fetching them from a scanner. The code I'm using to get the image from scanner returns references to java.awt.Image objects.

I can't increase memory by passing parameters to JVM, because I'm doing it in an applet and I don't want to bother user to make the configurations.

Comment: @banjillity I needed that ImageIcon to make sure that image.getWidth() and image.getHeight() don't return 0. I tried without that and sometimes I got 0 as the return value. It seems that creating an ImageIcon from an Image loads all pixels, so that getWidth() and getHeight() return valid values.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly save some heap by not holding all the images in a collection which you then iterate. Instead, retrieve and write each image as you get it. The `hasMoreImages()` and `scanner.getNextImage()` parts of my suggested code are one possible implemention of this.

I'd also question the wisdom of painting the image with a Graphics context, when it might already be in a state you can write with ImageIO. ImageIO.write() requires a RenderedImage, so a quick instance check might be good enough.

```
while( hasMoreImages() ) {
    Image image = scanner.getNextImage();

    if ( image instanceof RenderedImage) ) {
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile( "img", ".jpg" );
        ImageIO.write( (RenderedImage)image, "jpg", tempFile );
        files.add( tempFile );
    } else {
        // Do your ImageIcon code thing here.
    }
}
```

Comment: My Image is not a RenderedImage. It's an Image made by MemoryImageSource, filled outside of my Java code in a DLL. I just get a collection of Images by calling a function of that DLL. The memory allocation for Image and MemoryImageSource is done in DLL and does not affect my heap space. But when I want to save the Image from inside my java code, I needed to make BufferedImages out of Images and that made the heap full, I guess.

Comment: I was thinking of implementing a new java.awt.image.DataBuffer and create a custom BufferedImage. Is that gonna work?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that scanner images are **HUGE**  -- at 600 dpi, we're talking over 100 MB uncompressed per color A4 page.  Good scanners can get scans at thousands of DPI -- at 2000 DPI, a single uncompressed color page will be over 1 GB.  The size of good-quality scans catches most people unprepared when they first start working with them.

Unless you're running a 64-bit operating system with gigs and gigs of RAM, you're never going to fit more than a few images in memory.  Scanning in black & white or greyscale and at a lower resolution will help, but the best solution is to change how you handle images.

Don't get a collection of images in memory -- get a *piece* of each image at a time, and write out the image until complete.  Put your TWAIN driver and API to work -- let it pass you buffers with parts of an image until done.  You're probably better off using a Java library to do this than rolling your own image handling

---

Edit: links for Java TWAIN libraries

- [JTwain](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/overview.php)

Comment: Do you know any library that can do this for me?

Comment: I don't know enough about your specific DLL & connection to say for sure -- more info would help.  Bear in mind that there is a TON of software to just directly acquire from a TWAIN driver and write to disk though.  Any scanner will come with at least one, and I can name 3 off the top of my head as well.

Comment: As stated above, try to get the images from the TWAIN driver directly to disk and later access it to do whatever you need. The applet should be signed in order to get permissions to access local filesystem. Accepting an answer will close this question avoiding to appear automatically in the front page of SO.